# AND OR operator with SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, syntax, ssrs-2008

I am having issues with a SSRS query.

When I load this into an SSRS report the name parameter works and returns the correct results.
However the state, field, loc doesnt work when I search. It returns all the data in those columns. The filter doesnt work. (click View Report)

I have a feeling its the syntax around the AND OR?

[image]

TIA

```
select * from address..addressmaster
WHERE  (addressmaster.loc_name like '%' +  @loc_name + '%') 
or (addresumaster.[state] LIKE '%' +  @state + '%')
or (addressmaster.TCU like '%' + @TCU + '%') 
or (addressmaster.street_name like '%' + @street_name + '%')
```

Comment: show us what you really pass as parameters to the query , and show us what you get and what you expect

Comment: If any one of the parameters cause a character pattern on the right-hand side of a LIKE operation to resolve to '%%', you'll see all rows in the result, assuming the corresponding column value IS NOT NULL.

Comment: If I search for a loc name the report works as expected.
However if i clear that field out and search for state, tcu or street name it just returns everything in the table.
Whatever is in the where clause it works correctly. Anything in the OR doesnt return the filtered data. It just returns everything in that table.

Comment: Is your parameter set to allow Blank or NULLs? When a parameter is blank your WHERE is `STATE LIKE '%%'`. Change your ORs to ANDs and add a `OR @state = ''` to each AND inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd setup your parameters:

[image]

Then in the SQL you can check for the NULL value or filter using the value entered.

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM 
   [address]..[addressmaster]
WHERE
   1=1
   AND (@loc_name IS NULL OR [addressmaster].[loc_name] LIKE '%' + @loc_name + '%')
   AND (@state IS NULL OR [addresumaster].[state] LIKE '%' + @state + '%')
   AND (@TCU IS NULL OR [addressmaster].[TCU] LIKE '%' + @TCU + '%')
   AND (@street_name IS NULL OR [addressmaster].[street_name] LIKE '%' + @street_name + '%');
```